# How to get sleep data without healthkit in iOS 10

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, healthkit

I wants to get accurate sleep data into my iOS app without using health kit.
Please provide suggestions.

https://apple.news/As1Ja5ZpOSzOt--RV8NkIWQ

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what you want to achieve here? because for some specific scenarios, there is no way beyond using iOS healthKit!

Comment: @KarthickRamesh I want to display user sleep data in admin panel and i want it without health kit as it needs user permission.

Comment: Yes you can get it using motion manager.

Comment: @seggy could you explain to me how we can get this?

Comment: @HemantSolanki for that you have to retrive data from motion manager and do some calculation
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager

Answer (score 1):

No, for getting sleep data from iphone you need to use the health kit. Even if you use any third party frameworks for getting sleep data, internally it has to use health kit thus requires user permission for the same.
Any way asking permission is one time and hence it should not affect the user experience.

Comment: @HemantSolanki Oh, it seems you want to replace science and a work of multiple people for multiple months by a single stackoverflow answer? That won't work.

Comment: @Sulthan I want to know is there any way to get sleep data. i have searched and found above link. so i want to know other alternatives of that.i hope u got it.

Comment: @HemantSolanki They don't get the sleep data, they use phone sensors to create the sleep data.

Comment: @Sulthan yes i know that bro.they have their algorithms to create data from sensor.